# How to ignore "null" or empty properties in json, globally, using Spring configuration

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to return only the properties that have values, but the null ones are also being returned.

I know that there's an annotation that does this ( `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` ), but then I need these in every single entity class.

So, my question is: Is there a way to configure this globally through spring config? (avoiding XML, preferably)

EDIT: It seems that this question has been considered a duplicate, but I don't think so. The real question here is how to configure it through spring config, which I couldn't find in other questions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, this is as easy as:

```
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non_null
```

If not, then you can configure the ObjectMapper in the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter like so:

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for(HttpMessageConverter converter: converters) {
            if(converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)converter).getObjectMapper()
                mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to use 'spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = non_null' with newer Spring Boot (1.5.2)

Comment: The property from @DavidTinker didn't work for me, in Spring Boot 2.25, while the Java manual configuration worked

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Spring Boot (2.0+), use:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

Answer (score 6):

The programmatic alternative to [Abolfazl Hashemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3931900/abolfazl-hashemi)'s answer is the following:

```
/**
 * Jackson configuration class.
 */
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper buildObjectMapper() {
       return new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    }
}
```

This way, you're basically telling to the Spring container that, every time an `ObjectMapper` is used, only properties with non-null values are to be included in the mappings.

Another alternative, as per the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto-spring-mvc), for Jackson 2+, is to configure it in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

EDIT:

If, instead of `application.properties` one is relying on `application.yml`, then the following configuration should be used:

```
spring:
    jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use jackson ObjectMapper for generating json, you can define following custom ObjectMapper for this purpose and use it instead:

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
   <property name="serializationInclusion">
      <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include">NON_NULL</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```