# Do not include empty object to Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to create json with spring boot.

class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private PersonDetails details;

//     getters and setters...
}
```

impletentation:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("Apple");
person.setDetails(new PersonDetails());
```

So there is a instance of `Person` with empty `details` and this is exactly what Jackson is returning:

```
"person": {
    "name": "Apple",
    "details": {}
}
```

I want to have json **without** empty brackets `{}`:

```
"person": {
    "name": "Apple"
}
```

This question's didn't helped me:

- [How to tell Jackson to ignore empty object during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366524/how-to-tell-jackson-to-ignore-empty-object-during-deserialization)
- [How to ignore "null" or empty properties in json, globally, using Spring configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828536/how-to-ignore-null-or-empty-properties-in-json-globally-using-spring-configu)

**Update 1:**

I'm using Jackson 2.9.6

Comment: Custom serializer/deserializer for ignoring your empty specific object sounds as good solution. So e.g. `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` not working in this case because you haven't null object, you have object wich has no attribute filled. Why  do you want to ignore empty object in JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a custom serializer, jackson will include your object.

Solution 1 : Replace new object with null

```
person.setDetails(new PersonDetails());
```

with

```
person.setDetails(null);
```

and add

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Person {
```

Solution 2: Custom serializer

```
public class PersonDetailsSerializer extends StdSerializer<PersonDetails> {

    public PersonDetailsSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public PersonDetailsSerializer(Class<PersonDetails> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            PersonDetails personDetails, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // custom behavior if you implement equals and hashCode in your code
        if(personDetails.equals(new PersonDetails()){
           return;
        }
        super.serialize(personDetails,jgen,provider);
    }
}
```

and in your `PersonDetails`

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    @JsonSerialize(using = PersonDetailsSerializer.class)
    private PersonDetails details;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do so globally for all classes ?