# Remove null and empty objects in nested classes during serialization with Jackson and Lombok

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, camel-jackson

I'm trying to remove both null attributes and empty objects from a complex object during serialization using Camel-Jackson and Lombok.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869126/jackson-ignore-empty-objects-without-custom-serializer) and it works, but they're accessing to the attributes directly without using getters or setters, so when I use Lombok's @Getter and @Setter it doesn't seem to work:

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Getter
@Setter
public class School {
    private String name;
    @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = Room.class)
    private Room room;
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Room {
    private String name;
}
```

So when I use this:

```java
School school = new School();
school.setRoom(new Room());
String jsonPerson = mapper.writeValueAsString(school);
System.out.println("Linearized json: "+jsonPerson);
```

It works

`Linearized json: {}`

However if I don't create a new Room object for the School instance

```java
School school = new School();
String jsonPerson = mapper.writeValueAsString(school);
System.out.println("Linearized json: "+jsonPerson);
```

I'm getting

`{"room":null}`

So what could be the problem here? I also tried with manual Getters and Setters instead of Lombok's and it doesn't work as I expect.

I'm using camel-jackson 3.3 and lombok 1.18.12.

Answer (score 1):

When you define `@JsonInclude` at attribute level, it overrides the value at class level. That the reason why in your code, for null `Room`, room attribute is coming in output json

Now since we can define only one value, for our case either non_null or not_empty, we need to look for some other way.

With `JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM`, we can define our own filter class and in that filter class we can define an `equals` method which our own logic to show in output json.

For ensuring non_null and not_empty, below is a simple code. You can update the logic as you like

```
class RoomFilter {
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null)
        return  true;
    else if(obj instanceof Room) {
        if(((Room)obj).getName() == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
  }
}
```

In your `School` class update as below and it should give you your desired result

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = RoomFilter.class)
private Room room;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't want to implement custom filters because i have a lot of classes (complex object) but looks like there's no other choice. I will have to implement filters for all of them, or a big one with a lot of conditions in it.

Comment: Yup. That's seems to be the only way for now. Hope in the next version, they provide support for multiple attributes